# Python - Iterate over dataframe rows to remove time from datetime stamp

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe with one column which contains a datetime stamp (dtype: datetime64[ns]):

```
         Date          Docs
0 2016-06-01 04:48:23  45
1 2016-06-01 07:24:38  56
2 2016-07-01 08:27:26  87
3 2016-07-01 08:27:49  44
```

I'd like to iterate over each row to delete the time section of the Date to have a final result like this:

```
     Date     Docs
0 2016-06-01  45
1 2016-06-01  56
2 2016-07-01  87
3 2016-07-01  44
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: [`normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.normalize.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `dt.floor`:

```
df['Date'].dt.floor('D')
```

or

```
df['Date'].dt.normalize()

0   2016-06-01
1   2016-06-01
2   2016-07-01
3   2016-07-01
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

*Note: `dt.floor` returns datetime dtype*
*Where as `dt.date` returns string dtype*

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `dt.date`:

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.date
```

Example case:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
rng = pd.date_range('2019-01-01 01:01:00', periods=365, freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame(rng)
print(df[0])
```

Looks like:

```
0     2019-01-01 01:01:00
1     2019-01-02 01:01:00
2     2019-01-03 01:01:00
```

After applying `dt.date`:

```
df[0] = df[0].dt.date
print(df[0])
```

Looks like:

```
0      2019-01-01
1      2019-01-02
2      2019-01-03
```